# iOS textbox `.focus()` not focusing

Tags: javascript, ios, web

I have the following which is used to set focus to a textbox when a div is clicked. this works fine on the desktop and android but doesn't work in iOS (4, 5, or 6). there are lots of comments on the web about such issues but none of them have fixed my issue.

```
$("#div").bind("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("textbox").focus();
});
```

how would i get this to work on iOS?